# Why multiset union is not working when I'm trying to concatenate a null with some number in plsql?

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-types

So i have two nested tables and i want to make a new one with the elements from both of them but the first nested table have an null value and the second one an number and i want the result to be the number in the second one but he print the null value. It is possible to make a union between a null and an number with multiset union ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, it is possible to *"make a union between a null and an number with multiset union"*. But what you end up with is **two entries in the nested table:

```
SQL> update test 
  2  set marks = numberlist(null) multiset union all numberlist(42) 
  3  where id_std = 1 
  4 /
SQL> select id_std 
  2       , t2.column_value as mark 
  3  from test t1 
  4     , table(t1.marks) t2 
  5  /

ID_STD  MARK
------  ----
     1
     1    42

SQL>
```

I suspect this affect is actually what you're complaining about. However, the null mark is still a valid entry. If you want to overwrite it you need to provide different logic.